# how to recover OSX files (failing drive) using a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, mac, data-recovery

I need to recover some files from a failing drive (OSX, macbook drive) using Windows.
I dont have a Mac to work with.  Just a standalone drive that had osx installed.
What is the best way to do this?
I have access to a few revoery tools, recouva, getdataback, Paragon, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your utilities implicitly support HFS+ volumes, Windows wont work.  Windows cannot read HFS+ volumes out of the box.

You could boot off a Linux liveCD and install some of the free recovery tools onto a USB  drive.  I have used some of the Linux tools to recover files from a Mac.  Unfortunately, I dont remember which tool, but a Google search would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Keltari.
I did some research on HFS+ tools and I found Paragon HFS+ .
this acts like a 'driver' in windows that allows read/write onto HFS drives.  once you plugin an hfs+ drive, it acts like any other external drive in explorer.